# Using the Clipboard with MenuTreeToolStripItem

Tags: vb.net

Below is the code I have with regards to pressing a right mouse button on a menu strip item to copy the menu item., I've also copied the set text without the formatting. The problem I'm having is. it isn't auctioning/copying to the clipboard and I'm unsure why?

```
Private Sub MenuTreeToolStripMenuItem_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles MenuTreeToolStripMenuItem.MouseDown
        Select Case MouseButtons

            Case MouseButtons.Left
                'Left click

            Case MouseButtons.Right
                'Right click
                My.Computer.Clipboard.SetText("This is a test string.", System.Windows.Forms.TextDataFormat.Rtf)

        End Select
    End Sub
```

'alt version below here

```
Private Sub MenuTreeToolStripMenuItem_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles MenuTreeToolStripMenuItem.MouseDown
    Select Case MouseButtons

        Case MouseButtons.Left
            'Left click

        Case MouseButtons.Right
            'Right click
            My.Computer.Clipboard.SetText("This is a test string")

    End Select
End Sub
```

revised code

```
Private Sub MenuTreeToolStripMenuItem_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles MenuTreeToolStripMenuItem.MouseDown
    Select Case e.Button

        Case e.Button.Left
            'Left click

        Case e.Button.Right
            'Right click
            My.Computer.Clipboard.SetText("This is a test string.")
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: `System.Windows.Forms.TextDataFormat.Rtf` so far as I'm aware, that parameter isn't required to set text to the clipboard, so why have it?

Comment: I've been experimenting with other suggestions, but I was thinking the latter would be more robust but I can't get the clipboard to catch

Comment: No, you don't need it. Have you tried setting a breakpoint there?

Comment: I get a red line if I add a "break;" in either the case or if I've dimensioned it as an if then end if

Comment: I've shown my revision in the above but no clipboard changes, should I be declaring it outside of the event?

Comment: You shouldn't be doing `e.Button.Right`, it's still `MouseButtons.Right`. It could be that the control isn't firing the event.

Comment: tried with e.Button.Right and with MouseButton.Right but think there is something fundamental I'm missing here, neither hit the clipboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code wroks for me gracefully.

```
Private Sub MenuTreeToolStripMenuItem_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles MenuTreeToolStripMenuItem.MouseDown

    Select Case e.Button

        Case Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left
            'Left click

        Case Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right
            'Right click
            My.Computer.Clipboard.SetText("This is a test string.")
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: That's where I was going wrong, i wasn't declaring the Windows.Forms initially, just tested and it works my side, I appreciate the feedback there.